# Elementos dentro de un control de usuario en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen dia,

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# y estoy trabajando con Windows Forms, en la cual estoy utilizando Controles de usuario para poder utilizando el menú principal que yo definí como se muestra en la siguiente foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el menú que despliega a presionar en Usuario abre otro sub-menu en cual esta la opción "Agregar Usuario". Aquí es donde estoy creando el control de usuario. Lo que quisiera saber es porque no concuerda la posición donde pongo los elementos en el Control y al momento de inicializarla los muestra desfasados.

Anexo una foto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para lograr que queden alineados perfectamente tengo que encimar los elementos en este caso el textbox y el label como muestro en la siguiente foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguien que pueda ayudarme del porque sucede esto.

Gracias, ya había hecho un Control de Usuario y lo había trabajado sin problemas. Pero este no he logrado, saludos.

Comment: wpf o winforms? es casi mas importante que el lenguaje te diria...

Comment: WindowsForms, lo agrego.

Comment: Utiliza los distintos paneles que se incluyen en winforms, para eso son.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EzequieLopez yo tenia el mismo problema lo que realize es crear un ejemplo al label o texbox : **SizeChanged**

donde no importa si lo achicas o agranda siempre te va colocar el mismo lugar que estas definiendo.

espero haberte ayudado.

```
  private void lblcliente_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbln10.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - lbln10.Size.Width) / 2;
        }
```

Comment: perdon PieroDev No entendi mucho, para que se utiliza SizeChanged.

Comment: Buena tarde pedro, ya investigue un poco mas del evento y me sirvió muchísimo.

Comment: @EzequieLopez soy piero no pedro bro..!! espero que te haya servido siempre estoy para ayudarlos :)